# SOAP server classmap array not working on object in arrays

Tags: php, soap

I have a SOAP server (using Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover for the WSDL) created with its classmap passed as a parameter.

When my "ManageOrder" function is called, the received input has all its member types as defined in the classmap, except for the ones that are in an array (they keep being considered as "stdclass" objects even if they are specified in the classmap).

The class declared in PHP:

```
class TManageOrderInput // Has been simplified for the sake of readability
{       
    /** @var Torder **/
    public $orderHeader;  // This will be detected as Torder

    /** @var Torderdetailtax[] **/ // orderDetailTaxes[0] will be of type stdclass
    public $orderDetailTaxes;
}
```

The orderdetail and orderdetail array types in the WSDL:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfTorderdetailtax">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="soap-enc:Array">
        <xsd:attribute ref="soap-enc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:Torderdetailtax[]"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Torderdetailtax">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="orderdetailid" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="taxid" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="taxamount" type="xsd:double"/>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And here are the classmap and SOAP server creations:

```
    $classMap = array('classmap' => array( 
       'TManageOrderInput' => 'TManageOrderInput', 
       'TManageOrderOutput' => 'TManageOrderOutput', 
       'Torder' => 'Torder', 
       'Torderdetailtax' => 'Torderdetailtax'
    ));

    $server = new Zend_Soap_Server($wsdl, $classMap);
    $server->setClass('MDGSS');
    $server->handle();
```

Why would the types of the objects in the arrays still be detected as stdclass?

Am I missing something or is it just something not handled by the SOAP server?

Comment: I have the same problem but with the SoapClient class mapping. Did you manage the solve the problem?

Comment: No, as far as I remember I never solved this (I don't think it was a blocker on my side, had some workaround) @sidon

Comment: This is a [bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49070) in PHP; perhaps, [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830801/php-soapclient-call-response-missing-parts-of-answer/5409920#5409920) can assist you. This bug relates to the [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383522) from official RFC where, it seems, you need to specify exactly how many items the array has, and [] just won't cut it unless you use minOccurs/maxOccurs.